# I am not sure how to view the TLS session details when using Curl

Tags: c++, ssl, curl

I am not entirely sure if I am using Curl correctly as it is the first time I have ever used it but I need to be able to read the details of a TLS session between me and whatever server I have connected to.

My problem is I have used 
"curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION, &tls)"

Where tls is a curl_tlssessioninfo struct. But I actually have no clue as to the structure of it and I can't find anywhere that points it out and therefore cannot display the information i have just read.

Of course I could be going about this completely the wrong way but I have been pouring over the manual for Curl for quite some time now.
The language I am using is C++ and I am in a Ubuntu environment, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What "details of a TLS session" are you interested in exactly?

Comment: @DanielStenberg Specifically I am looking for the host certificate, cipher suite used, session ID and the master secret that are generated from the TLS handshake. As I said I am not sure if I am even going about this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

LibCURL supports a number of different SSL implementations (backends), and the information returned from `CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION` (and the new variant, `CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR`) is also implementation-dependent.

As the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.html) explains, a pointer to the `curl_tlssessioninfo` structure is returned, which is defined as:

```
struct curl_tlssessioninfo {
  curl_sslbackend backend;
  void *internals;
};
```

Here `backend` is an enumeration specifying the actual type of the SSL context information stored in `internals`:

- CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL: `SSL_CTX*` (or `SSL*`) ([docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/))
- CURLSSLBACKEND_GNUTLS: `gnutls_session_t` ([docs](https://gnutls.org/manual/gnutls.html#Obtaining-session-information))
- CURLSSLBACKEND_SCHANNEL: `CtxtHandle*` (Windows [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379326(v=vs.85).aspx))
- CURLSSLBACKEND_DARWINSSL: `SSLContext*` (Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport))
- CURLSSLBACKEND_AXTLS: `SSL*`
- CURLSSLBACKEND_MBEDTLS: `mbedtls_ssl_context*`
- CURLSSLBACKEND_NSS: `PRFileDesc*`
- etc.

When you build libcurl for your project, you specify the SSL backend to use, so you should know which SSL backend(s) you use, cast the `internals` pointer to the right type and use the corresponding headers and API of that backend to further extract the necessary information.

Comment: I know for a fact that the backend being uses is OpenSSL but I am still confused as to how I would go about accessing the data. In this case would I cast internals to SSL_CTX?
The whole reason I am using Curl was to not have to deal so much with OpenSSL as I could not find much documentation at all to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for code examples, one of the best places to look is github.

This [github project](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp) is a object oriented C++ wrapper of curl.

Looking at [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.html) example, following is a sample code of `CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR` which supersedes deprecated `CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION`.

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  struct curl_tlssessioninfo *tls;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR, &tls);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Hope this helps.